# Adding New viewcontroller to current stack

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I am inserting a ViewController into my current stack. And trying to perform popviewcontroller like this.

```
 var viewControllersArray: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers


    if(dm.isLoginViewLoaded)
    {
        print("Login view already loaded")

    }

    else
    {
        print("Login view havent load before")
        let myviewcontroller:LoginViewController=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LOGIN") as! LoginViewController
        let index=viewControllersArray.count-2
        viewControllersArray.insert(myviewcontroller, at: index)
        // update navigationController viewControllers
        self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(viewControllersArray, animated:false)

    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

But why I cant achive what im trying to do. Even in this second condition satisfying my viewcontroller always pushing to Root viewcontroller. I want to add a new viewcontroller in between my current view controller and root viewcontroller, and perform the pop operation. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let arrController:[UIViewController] = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)!//array of all controllers in navigation stack
    for vc in arrController
    {
      if (type(of: vc)  == type(of: LoginViewController
))//check exist or not
      {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController((arrController[(arrController.index(of: vc))!]), animated: true)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to check if it exists or not.. I know in it loads without loginviewcontroller. So I want to insert it manually and popto it

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply "mis-counted" the array position. Your index should be:

```
let index = viewControllersArray.count - 1   // *not* -2
```

However, this may be a little more "robust" method:

```
@IBAction func popToLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    if let navVC = self.navigationController {

        var bFoundLogin = false

        var viewControllersArray = navVC.viewControllers

        for vc in viewControllersArray.reversed() {
            if vc is LoginViewController {
                // we found LoginViewController in stack, so
                //  pop to it (even if it's multiple levels back)
                bFoundLogin = true
                navVC.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
                // found it, so break out of the for loop
                break
            }
        }

        if !bFoundLogin {

            // we didn't find LoginViewController in stack, so
            //  replace current VC with LoginVC

            //if let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LOGIN") as? LoginViewController {
            if let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "AnimConstraints", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LOGIN") as? LoginViewController {

                // insert loginVC before last item
                viewControllersArray.insert(loginVC, at: viewControllersArray.count - 1)
                // set the NavVC's array of controllers
                navVC.setViewControllers(viewControllersArray, animated: false)
                // pop back one level (to our inserted loginVC)
                navVC.popViewController(animated: true)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Using a loop to "find" `LoginViewController` in the stack allows you to "pop to it" even if it's not the "next one in line", and also removes the need for your `dm.isLoginViewLoaded` tracking (unless you're using that elsewhere).